# APEX 5.1 Validation using PL/SQL Regular Expression

Tags: regex, validation, oracle-apex

Have searched Stack Overflow & cannot find an answer to this specific question. I have a PL/SQL expression validation which works, the USERNAME is an email address...

```
regexp_like (:P2_USERNAME, '^[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9.__.-]+@[A-Za-z0-9._.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$')
```

Now the customer wants to be able to have an email address with a special character in it. So I changed the validation script as follows...

```
regexp_like (:P2_USERNAME, '^[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9.__.-\&\\#]+@[A-Za-z0-9._.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$');
```

It no longer works, I get the error message if I attempt to use an email address with an & or a # in it. For example I have the following email address saved in the database...

firstnm-lastnm&123@outlook.com

However this will not work with this validation. Assume it is something really easy that I am missing - your help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

discovered the script needed to be like this...

regexp_like (:P2_USERNAME, '^[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9.__.-\&\#\-]+@[A-Za-z0-9._.-]+.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$')

The same, yet very slightly different.